# Creating flag using fuzzywuzzy matching between two datasets in python

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzywuzzy

I have two datasets df1 and df2 ,both having the following columns:

```
|city   |state  |address_id |address             |postal_code
|A      |X      |10         |flat 123,abc lane   |400000
```

I want to create a binary flag for each address_id in df1 based on whether a similar address is present in df2. My original datasets are pretty big (df1= 5k rows, df2= 200K rows). I tried out the following set on codes on small data samples:

```
for i in df1.index:
      v=[]
      for j in df2.index:
            vi = df1.get_value(i, 'address')
            vj = df2.get_value(j, 'address')
            v.append(max(fuzz.ratio(vi, vj),
               fuzz.partial_ratio(vi, vj),
               fuzz.token_sort_ratio(vi, vj),
               fuzz.token_set_ratio(vi, vj)))
      vmax=max(v)
      if vmax>=80:
           df1.loc[i,'flag']='Y'
      else:
           df1.loc[i,'flag']='N'
```

But this won't work on a larger dataset. Is there a way to optimize this? postal_code can be used as a condition while fuzzy matching, to lessen the number of iterations. Also, maybe I can stop iterating as soon as we reach a v= 80.

```
for i in df1.index:
    v=1
    while v<=80:
        for j in df2.index:
            vi = df1.get_value(i, 'address')
            vj = df2.get_value(j, 'address')
            v= max(fuzz.ratio(vi, vj),
               fuzz.partial_ratio(vi, vj),
               fuzz.token_sort_ratio(vi, vj),
               fuzz.token_set_ratio(vi, vj))
        if v>=80:
           df1.loc[i,'flag']='Y'
        else:
           df1.loc[i,'flag']='N'
```

Just started with python, so kind of stuck here. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried some of fuzzywuzzy comparisons over 2 DFs and as far as my research went, there is no fast way to do it. The fact that you use 4 `fuzz` methods slow down your script too. One way could be to use 'process.extractOne()` and create a function such:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process
def fw_process(row_df1):
    # Select the addresses from df2 with same postal_code
    df2_select_add = df2['address'][df2['postal_code'] == row_df1['postal_code']]
    ad_1 = row_df1['address']
    # Find the best match for ad_1 in df2_select_add and get the ratio with [1] 
    # for the name of df2_select_add , use [0]
    if process.extractOne(ad_1, df2_select_add)[1] >= 80:
        return 'Y'
    else:
        return 'N'
```

Then to create your column flag in `df1`, you do:

```
df1['flag'] = df1.apply(fw_process , axis=1)
```

NOTE: the name `df2` is not called as parameter of the function which is not the cleaner way, but if it's define before in your code with this name it works.

If you want to keep the 4 `fuzz` methods, then you can create the function on the same idea:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
def fw_fuzz ( row_df1):
    # Select the addresses from df2 with same postal_code
    df2_select_add = df2['address'][df2['postal_code'] == row_df1['postal_code']]
    ad_1 = row_df1['address']
    # Get the max of the max of the 4 fuzz comparison between ad_1 and df2_select_add
    if max (df2_select_add.apply(lambda x: max(fuzz.ratio(ad_1, x), fuzz.partial_ratio(ad_1, x),
                                                fuzz.token_sort_ratio(ad_1, x),fuzz.token_set_ratio(ad_1, x)))) >= 80:
        return 'Y'
    else:
        return 'N'
```

and then:

```
df1['flag'] = df1.apply(fw_fuzz, axis=1)
```

Comment: On running the 1st code, i am getting the following error:
  File "<ipython-input-125-e36ff0303890>", line 7, in fw_process
    if process.extractOne(ad_1, df2_select_add)[1] >= 80:

TypeError: ("'NoneType' object is not subscriptable", 'occurred at index 0') . And on running the 2nd code, i'm getting this error: File "<ipython-input-123-5faf8c6748a0>", line 6, in fw_fuzz
    if max (df2_select_add.apply(lambda x: max(fuzz.ratio(ad_1, x), fuzz.partial_ratio(ad_1, x),

ValueError: ('max() arg is an empty sequence', 'occurred at index 0'). Please help.

Comment: your problem could be that there is some `postal_code` in `df1` not in `df2` then you have an empty `df2_select_add`. One option could be to check if `df2_select_add` is empty. After the line 'df2_select_add = ...' you can add `if df2_select_add.empty:
        return 'N'`